# Is it possible to show each legends aligned with each bar in chart.js

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, chart.js3

I made a horizontal bar chart using Chart.js. In default setting all the legends are shown all together like this

[image]

there is no gap among them. I want to show each legend aligned with each bar like this

[image]

I tried so many solutions but none of them worked. Is it possible to show legends right and center aligned with each bar in chart.js?

I am using Chart.js (v.3.7)

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you are looking for can possibly be achieved by using the padding option in the [Legend Label Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) and trying to find the correct value.
This could look something like this:

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    padding: 15 // change according to testing
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You would usually not use a legend for this but instead label the axis directly as described in the link below.

Have a look at the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration

It provides an example on how to use axis labels like that:

```js
// config
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          crossAlign: 'far',
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

// setup
const labels = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"]
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My dataset',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [65, 59, 80],
  }]
};
```

Comment: In this document did not show nay usages of the legend. Or I couldn't get what you said. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Have a look at the section called Tick Alignment, the link sometimes doesn't directly jump to it unfortunately. As I said, you would not use the legend for this and instead use the axis ticks to achieve the look you want.

Comment: No, I have to use the legend not the axis ticks. I just need space among legends so that they get aligned with each bar

Comment: @Chris As no initial code to go off was provided, what is one supposed to do when trying to refer to the official documentation?

Comment: @Chris I see. This makes sense. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Alien maybe have a look at my updated answer. :)